# Private sub Worksheet_Change multiple range

Tags: excel, colors, shapes, worksheet

My Private sub color change of shape, how to apply it to the multiple shapes in Worksheet.
Ex.: range ("a1") 
     range ("a2") 
     range ("a3") ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("a1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
       If Target.Value = 1 Then
        With activesheet.Shapes("BOT1").Fill
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 155, 0)
           .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 155, 0)
           .TwoColorGradient msoGradientVertical, 1
        End With
    ElseIf Target.Value = 2 Then
        With activesheet.Shapes("BOT1").Fill
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
           .BackColor.RGB = RGB(210, 210, 0)
           .ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
        End With
ElseIf Intersect(Target, Range("a2")) Is Nothing Then 
If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
       If Target.Value = 1 Then
        With activesheet.Shapes("BOT2").Fill
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 155, 0)
           .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 155, 0)
           .TwoColorGradient msoGradientVertical, 1
        End With
    ElseIf Target.Value = 2 Then
        With activesheet.Shapes("BOT2").Fill
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
           .BackColor.RGB = RGB(210, 210, 0)
           .ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
        End With
```

Comment: If you want to all shapes just loop through shapes on sheet. If you want specific shapes then create an array storing the shape names and then loop through that array

Comment: You can probably get rid of the `If IsNumeric` since you are testing for `If Target.Value = 1`. If the value is not numeric, it won't equal 1 so the test seems redundant

Comment: I will test. but how join it code? the private sub.sorry for the writing, i'm brazilian.

Comment: Help. I can't finish this code.